# Using ResultSet to return string value from database but method skips the "Try" clause?

Tags: java, mysql, database, select, resultset

Why is my following code:

```
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
pw.println(getValueOf(SQL, "lastName");
```

not printing anything after passing it into my method:

```
public static String getValueOf(String sql, String colName)
{
   String result = "";

   try
   {
       Connection conn = (Connection) accessDB.connecttoDB(); // pre-defined funct in my other class that works
       PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

       while (rs.next())
            result = rs.getString(colName);

       conn.close();

       return result;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return result;
}
```

In other words, why does it seem to be skipping the "try" clause entirely and just jumping to return the empty "" result at the end?

My SQL statment:

```
String SQL = "SELECT lastName FROM customers WHERE firstName=\"Bob\";";
```

I do have an entry for the person "Bob" (his lastname is "Mike") in my Customers table.

**My Customers Table:**

lastName / firstName / address / email

EDIT

It works correctly if I change the return type to **"void"** but I actually need a String value.

Alternate code:

```
 public static void getValueOf(String sql, String colName, PrintWriter pw)
    {

       try
       {
           Connection conn = (Connection) accessDB.connecttoDB(); // pre-defined funct in my other class that works
           PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
           ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

           while (rs.next())
                pw.println(rs.getString(colName)); // This does print out to the webpage as "Mike"

           conn.close();


       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Comment: If it is not returning at the first `return result;` then you must either have an exception that you are not telling us about, of this is **not** the code that is running

Comment: *It works correctly if I change the return type to "void"*  - This is nonsense

Comment: I've tried it by changing the parameters to:  (String sql, String colName, PrintWriter pw) when the return type is void.  Obviously also deleting the result variable since it's not needed to return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your last edit, I would guess that you have **more** than **one** records.

So change your code to

```
 if (rs.next()) {
        result = rs.getString(colName);
 }
```

And also, your code does not skip that `try` block

Comment: Ok, it now works with the "if" clause.  Mind explaining why it wasn't working with a "while" clause?

Comment: Read the top line of my answer

Comment: Thanks, here you go.

Comment: @5120bee Thanks.  After your edit showing the code that works, this question became a good question